# Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments - When convert Swift 1.2 to 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm converting a project from Swift 1.2 to 2. The following code:

```
func pageControlChanged(pageControl: UIPageControl) {
    // get the current and upcoming page numbers
    let currentTutorialPage = (viewControllers[0] as! partyStepViewController).page
    let upcomingTutorialPage = pageControl.currentPage

    // what direction are we moving in?
    let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = upcomingTutorialPage < currentTutorialPage ? .Reverse : .Forward

    // set the new page, animated!
    setViewControllers([partyStepForPage(upcomingTutorialPage)],
        direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

gave me the following error:

> Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

for the particular line of code:

```
let currentTutorialPage = (viewControllers[0] as! partyStepViewController).page
```

What does this error message mean? How can I fix it?

Here are some links to my code:

- [a zipfile of the whole project](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/SwiftSV-12-UIPageViewController-uber-challenge-finished-1_0.zip), not converted to Swift 2
- [`partyStepViewController`](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/37c68775)
- [`partyPagedViewController`](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/157fe25d)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `viewControllers` [is now an Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/viewControllers).

So you have to unwrap it before you can subscript it: `viewControllers![0]`